# Building with CMake adds prefix "OFF" to the tests. How to get rid of that?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, c++14

I have a CMake project with following structure:

```
project
    |- src
    |    |- plugins
    |    |      |- class1
    |    |      |     |- class1.hpp
    |    |      |     |- class1.cpp
    |    |      |     |- CMakeLists.txt
    |    |      |- class2
    |    |            |- class2.hpp
    |    |            |- class2.cpp
    |    |            |- CMakeLists.txt
    |    |- tests
    |           |- CMakeLists.txt
    |           |- test_1
    |           |     |- test.cpp
    |           |     |- CMakeLists.txt
    |           |- test_2
    |                 |- test.cpp
    |                 |- CMakeLists.txt
    |- CMakeLists.txt
```

The contents of the CMakeLists is as follows:

- `project/CMakeLists`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)
project(project-name)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
add_subdirectory(src/plugins/class1)
add_subdirectory(src/plugins/class2)

## Tests
option(CMAKE_BUILD_TESTS "Build tests" ON)
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(src/tests)
endif()
```

- `project/src/plugins/class1/CMakeLists.txt` (similarly for class2):

```
project(plugin_1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
add_library(class1 SHARED class1.cpp class1.hpp)
target_compile_options(class1 PRIVATE $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:-Wall>)
install(TARGETS class1
    COMPONENT bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
```

- `project/src/tests/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)
project(unit-tests)
add_subdirectory(test_1)
add_test(NAME test_1 COMMAND test_1)
add_subdirectory(test_2)
add_test(NAME test_2 COMMAND test_2)
```

- `project/src/tests/test_1/CMakeLists.txt` (similarly for test_2):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)
project(test_1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/plugins/class1)
add_executable(test_1 test.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(test_1 PUBLIC UNIT_TESTS)
target_link_libraries(test_1 class1)
install(TARGETS test_1
  COMPONENT bin
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
```

I am building the project as follows:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TESTS=ON ..
$ make && make install
```

#### Question:

Whilst building the project, it builds the tests as: `OFFtest_1` and `OFFtest_2`. How to get rid if the 'OFF' prefix? Where is it coming from?

Comment: please show a [mre] with the cmake file you are using and the full cmake command line

Comment: Added the required info. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Is there no `cmake_minimum_required` in your scripts? `CMake command line being used` So you are building in a subdirectory? `executable OFFtest` But there is no `add_executable(test` in your files, so that `test` becomes `OFFtest` after adding `OFF` as you stated it happens. Are you sure you are running cmake in the directory with these files? Is `Tests` bulid by yur cmake? Is `OFF` added to `Tests`?  Is the `OFF` added also to `MyClass`? Could you post the full output of cmake build stage?

Comment: The output `Linking CXX executable OFFTest` doesn't correspond to the `CMakeLists.txt` files you have added to the question post. Probably, you have built some **other** project. Or you have very specific settings for your project, which causes renaming `Tests`  executable to `OFFTest`. If you have such settings, then you should definitely be aware of them.

Comment: Does **created files** have `OFF` prefix? Or is it just an `OFF` in the **output** of CMake? Does 'class1` and `class2` targets are output with `OFF` prefix too? If this is only an output which is affected, then it could be that your **terminal** incorrectly outputs `OFF` instead of **coloring** a target name. You could try to build your project in the other terminal.

Comment: `class1` and `class2` gets built properly as libs. However the `OFF` prefix is only present for the executable `test_1` and `test_2`.